# How do I move to the beginning of a visual block from a vimscript function?

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode, functions, filetype-xml

Suppose i have several lines of text:

```
line1 line1
line2 line2
line3 line3
```

I want to create a vimscript function that has the following result:

```
<itemizedlist>
<listitem><para>line1 line1</para></listitem>
<listitem><para>line2 line2</para></listitem>
<listitem><para>line3 line3</para></listitem>
</itemizedlist>
```

How do i use '< and '> to move to the beginning and end of multiline visual selection inside a vimscript function? vim writes me "Not an editor command: '<"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply?

```
normal! '<
```

However, I would highly recommend seeing if there is a way to accomplish what you want via simpler (Ex) commands. If you need to do some work over a range, Ex commands are good at it.

For example, visually select the lines (e.g., `Vap`), then `:'<,'>normal! Isome text` and `:'<,'>normal! Asome text`. Then you should be able to get the lines above and below via the `'<` and `'>` registers and put the remaining text.

Comment: Aside: functions defined without `[range]` called with a range will be run once on each line, so you could have a function to do the surround on each line, and then separately to handle the above and below.